# How to generate password on the following standard

Tags: c#

I want to generate a password on the following standard.
One capital letter
10 Small letters
four numbers at the end
Code I have

```
 //Gnerating a random password
        string allowedChars = "";

        allowedChars = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,";

        allowedChars += "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,";

        allowedChars += "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,!,@,#,$,%,&,?";

        char[] sep = { ',' };

        string[] arr = allowedChars.Split(sep);

        string passwordString = "";

        string tempString = "";
        int PasswordLength = 16;

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(PasswordLength); i++)

        {

            tempString = arr[rand.Next(0, arr.Length)];

            passwordString += tempString;

        }
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Pick one capital letter at random, 10 small letters at random, 4 digits at random, put them into a common list and shuffle it (there should be many examples here on Stack Overflow, otherwise google for Fisher-Yates shuffle), and you should have your password. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to determine whether this will actually produce a good password or not.

Comment: @Liam for some reason the password I remember when I see that cartoon is "Mr.Ed", and that is always too short for most sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create both an upper and a lower value set. We have code for changing case. You could also extract the actual picking to a separate method, that would make it easier to test.

Here is my attempt:

```
void Main()
{
    char[] lowerCase = new char[] {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char[] numbers = new char[] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    // Create the Random outside the method to avoid reseeding
    Random random = new Random();
    // Pick one char and make it uppercase
    string password = PickRandomValueFromValueSet(1, lowerCase, random).ToUpper();
    // Pick 10 lowercase chars
    password+= PickRandomValueFromValueSet(10, lowerCase, random);
    // Pick 4 digits
    password+= PickRandomValueFromValueSet(4, numbers, random);
    Console.Out.WriteLine.(password);
}

string PickRandomValueFromValueSet(int number, char[] valueSet, Random random)
{
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        result += valueSet[random.Next(0, valueSet.Length)];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I don't see why `!`,`@`,`#`,`$`,`%`,`&` and `?` were allowed as numbers in the question. I have omitted those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add different chars to your password string in this way:

```
    string lowerChars = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,";
    string[] lowerCharsArr = lowerChars.Split(sep);
    string upperChars = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,";
    string[] upperCharsArr = upperChars.Split(sep);
    string numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0";
    string[] numbersArr = numbers.Split(sep);
    string others = "!,@,#,$,%,&,?";
    string[] othersArr = others.Split(sep);


    string passwordString = "";

    int PasswordLength = 16;

    Random rand = new Random();

    passwordString += upperChars[rand.Next(0, upperChars.Length)];

    for (int i = 1; i < Convert.ToInt32(PasswordLength -4); i++)
    {
        passwordString += lowerChars[rand.Next(0, lowerChars.Length)];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        passwordString += numbersArr[rand.Next(0, numbersArr.Length)];
    }
```

Comment: The last comma in lowerChars and upperChars will lead to null strings in the arrays and will allow creating passwords shorter than 15 characters and not starting with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do this, optionally shuffling the result with the extension method `.Shuffle`, but if you really want to keep the order of upper first, then lower, then 4 digit/symbols at the end just leave that out.

```
namespace PasswordGen
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static Random _random = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nonAlphaSymbols = "1234567890!@#$%&?";
            var password = new[] { (char)_random.Next('A', 'Z' + 1) } // upper case character
                .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(a => (char)_random.Next('a', 'z' + 1)) // 10 lower case
                .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(a => nonAlphaSymbols[_random.Next(0, nonAlphaSymbols.Length)]))) // 4 from nonAlpha
                .Shuffle(); // optional, if you want to shuffle the outcome

            Console.WriteLine(new string(password.ToArray()));
        }

    }

    public static class Extensions
    {   
        private static Random _random = new Random();

        public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input)
        {
            List<T> output = new List<T>(input);
            for (int i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
            {
                var swapTarget = _random.Next(i, output.Count - 1);
                T temp = output[swapTarget];
                output[swapTarget] = output[i];
                output[i] = temp;
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BLOEgy

Comment: That's a very elegant solution, but you would need to do something about the upper bounds on `Random.Next`, since they are exclusive. You wouldn't be able generate anything with a *Z* or *z* or *?*.

Comment: Sorry (too late to edit my comment), you would be able to generate a `?` since you are using the length, but not `Z` or `z`.